# How to set Custom Fields Notifications in HP Project and Portfolio Management(PPM)?

Tags: notifications

I am using HP Project and Portfolio Management(PPM) tool and I am adding a custom field in my request type which has date as value. Now my requirement is to send the email notifications to the users once the date mentioned in the custom field crosses the system date.

I had tried to set the notification for field level from Notification tab but not getting the custom fields in the list. All the fields, which is available, are pre-configured fields.

So, can anyone suggest me how to implement this requirement? And also where the changes need to be done If any required to implement this?

Please answer in detail and also reply soon.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

PPM notifications can be configured on pre-defined events, like a certain transition, or timeout etc...
One possible solution for this scenario is to have timeouts on your decision step. Time out goes to an execution step, which checks for the date condition. If the condition is met it fires the notification. Else it just returns to the original decision step. 
The downside of this work around is that there will be transaction details added once daily. Also the last update date of the request keeps updating daily, which is not ideal if you want to track what was the last time an end user update the request.

It is a workaround cause of the restrictions around notification events.
And if you have a large workflow, I would not recommend this work around.